# Where to save your .htaccess file on Apache for 404 page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, custom-errors, file-not-found

I have an Apache web server running on Amazon EC2 and I am trying to make a custom 404 page which I did, but I want it to popup when a mistyped or wrong URL is requested. This is my .htaccess code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I saved my .htaccess file in my /var/www/html directory. Am I doing something wrong? Because when I typed in a wrong url, the default Apache 404 Error keeps popping up and I don't want that to drive visitors away. Is this possible? **Thanks!!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

confirm that AllowOverride directive is set to All in your httpd.conf


secondly .htaccess should be kept inside the root directory of your code.

Comment: I tried getting to my httpd.conf file but I can't find it. And for the .htaccess to work, I put it in the root directory but I still doesn't work.

Comment: which operating system are you using in amazon EC2?

Comment: for linux it is in /etc/httpd.conf

Comment: there is no file called httpd.conf in the ect directory. Am I supposed to create one?

Comment: no it will be in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf sorry for forgetting the folder in between

Comment: You were right about setting AllowOverride directive to all in the httpd.conf file. Now my .htaccess file works so I set more mods to the server. But the httpd.conf file is located in the directory /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. Thanks for all your help! Also, do you know any sites that offer tutorials on more .htaccess mods?

Comment: There are many sites explaining the details of htaccess. One of them: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used the same code:

`ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`
But instead of putting it in my .htaccess file, which never worked, I put the same code in my httpd.conf file which I found under the directory `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` Thanks for all your help!